# How to do recursion for recursive data type in function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to implement `menu` function that returns all titles from custom data type `Page`

```
data Page = Text String
         | Title String [Page] deriving(Show)
menu :: Page -> [String]
menu (Text a) = []
menu (Title name content ) = [name]
```

But I want also this function will work also for some "hierarchy" of pages, for example, like in `index` :

```
index = Title "Home" [
  Title "Welcome!"[
    Text "Hello World!", 
    Title "Lorem"[Text "ipsum"]],
  Title "dolor"[
    Title "no title" [Text "Haskell"],
    Title "Look!" [Text "test"]],
  Title "Finish" [Text "It will be look great"]]
```

I done some functions for this, but I have no idea how to start recursion for "hierarchy"  `Page`

```
menu :: Page -> [String]
menu (Text a) = []
menu (Title name content ) = [name]
```

The output is

```
*Main> menu index
["Home"]
```

But can I do list of all `Title` in `index`  ?

Thanks a lot in advance for answer!

Comment: You have a list of pages; map `menu` over that, and you'll get a list of lists. Concatenate those lists, then prepend `name` to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is as follows:

```hs
data Page = Text String
         | Title String [Page] deriving(Show)
menu :: Page -> [String]
menu (Text a) = [a]
menu (Title name content) = name : concatMap menu content

data Page = Text String
         | Title String [Page] deriving(Show)
menu :: Page -> [String]
menu (Text a) = [a]
menu (Title name content) = name : concatMap menu content
```

A small test:

```
λ> menu index
["Home","Welcome!","Hello World!","Lorem","ipsum","dolor","no title","Haskell","Look!","test","Finish","It will be look great"]
```

We are using [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap).

Since `Text a` is a leaf, we return the extracted `a` which is its `String` in a list as `[a]`.

`Title name content` has 2 parts. `name` is just a string, so we add it to the list and recursively call `menu`. But we can't just `map` `menu` over `content`, since content is a list of `Page`s. That means that we have a list of recursive data types. So we use `concatMap` that just concatenates the lists that are produced by each `Page` in the list.

If you like to keep track of whether a string was a `Title` or a `Text`:

```hs
data Page = Text String
         | Title String [Page] deriving(Show)
menu :: Page -> [String]
menu (Text a) = ["Text " ++ a]
menu (Title name content) = ("Title " ++ name) : concatMap menu content
```